# How to get the next highest interval of nine from a number

Tags: java, bukkit

I've made a class that will require me to get the next highest interval of nine when I get a number. Here is my current code.

```
int slot1 = (int) Math.floor(opposingPlayers/9.0);
int slot2 = slot1++;
int slot3 = slot2*9;
```

Opposing players is returning one. However when I run the code,

```
slot1 is equal to 1 
slot2 is equal to 0 
slot3 is equal to 0
```

However it should be slot1 = 0 slot2 = 1 slot3 = 9

I've only tested this with opposing players returning one, but it shouldn't change anything.

Comment: `int slot2 = slot1++;` increments the variable `slot1` but returns the old value of `slot1` (since it's post-incremeting). I think you meant `slot2 = slot1 + 1;`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch 0 is the first slot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slot1++` sets `slot2` to `slot1` (0), then icrements `slot1`. You need this:

```
int slot1 = (int) Math.floor(opposingPlayers/9.0);
int slot2 = slot1 + 1;
int slot3 = slot2*9;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the next highest interval of nine.

```
number + (9 - (number % 9))
```